# Regex Expression to check if two strings are equal but contain different superscripts

Tags: python, regex

I am comparing two pdf versions and providing differences between them. One issue I have is that for some words that are identical between versions, they have different superscripts. Even though the superscripts are different, I am not interested in flagging it as a difference since it creates too much meaningless noise

For example:

Old PDF  - "This is a wordᵃᵃᵃ"

New PDF  - "This is a wordᵇᵇᵇ"

This creates a lot of noise, and I am not interested in flagging this as a difference so I am trying to create a regex pattern that I can use to ignore it

I need to create a pattern that checks that the root of the word is identical, and is followed by some superscript chars

here is what I have so far:

```
pattern = '[a-zA-Z]+[\u02b0-\u207f]'
```

I need the first part to instead check that the root of the string is identical, followed by some superscript character(s)

Any thoughts? Is there some better way to identify these words?

Comment: Use capturing groups and compare them for equality.

Comment: Why use a Regex for that?

Comment: @ThomasWeller Do you know of another way I can tackle this? I know its easy to check if two words are the same, but I need to have that plus any superscript characters afterwards

Comment: Sure: use strings. You can index strings into single characters. And you can use isalpha() and other methods on those.

Comment: @Jim, are they actual Unicode superscript characters?  Or, are they just a result of a graphics process, e.g., smaller font size, and the base-line is moved upwards.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest taking look at [`unicodedata.category`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.category) and using it to eliminate `Lm` (modifier letter) characters following way

```
import unicodedata
s1 = "This is a wordᵃᵃᵃ"
s2 = "This is a wordᵇᵇᵇ"
s1 = ''.join(i for i in s1 if unicodedata.category(i) != "Lm")
s2 = ''.join(i for i in s2 if unicodedata.category(i) != "Lm")
print(s1) # This is a word
print(s2) # This is a word
print(s1==s2) # True
```

However keep in mind it removes all symbols from [`Lm`](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/category/Lm) category, not strictly letters.

Comment: Could you help me understand what is going on here?

Comment: @Jim read the doc about **generator expressions**, and **list comprehensions**

Comment: is this actually modifying the data though?

Comment: @Jim if you don't want that use different variable names for the result of `''.join()`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, assure that they are actual Unicode superscript characters.
They *could* just be the result of some type of graphics process, in which the font is reduced, and the text is moved upward.

A basic copy and paste to a textbox should display the actual characters.

You are using a range of U+02B0 to U+207F.

These are both the starting codepoints for two different blocks.
*[Wikipedia – List of Unicode characters – Spacing modifier letters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters#Spacing_modifier_letters)*.
*[Wikipedia – List of Unicode characters – Superscripts and Subscripts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters#Superscripts_and_Subscripts)*.

As a note, Unicode deems several types of characters as *superscripted*, which can be found on the following page.
*[Wikipedia – Unicode subscripts and superscripts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts)*.

The specifc *superscript* characters you provided are not from either of those blocks.

The ᵃ is U+1D43, and the ᵇ is U+1D47.  Which are both found within the following block.
*[Wikipedia – Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts – Superscript IPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts#Superscript_IPA)*.

So, you'll need to use a range starting at U+1D43.  And, I believe the limit should be, U+1DBF, although I'm unsure.

And, as a note, you may want to capture hyphenated words.

```
(?i)([a-z-]+)[\u1d43-\u1dab]+
```